# Setting a Limit With BeautifulSoup

Tags: python, beautifulsoup, limit

I'm using the following code to extract the PE ratio from NATI on [Yahoo!](http://finance.yahoo.com/q/ks?s=NATI%20Key%20Statistics) I have been through crummy's documentation and I 'almost' understand nextSibling, .content and previousSibling ( I suspect that they are related to XML and DOM). I am still trying to figure it out since I think in the long run using that code will be prettier than the one below. What I am wondering is it possible to set a range with limit...i.e. 2:3(search only 2 through 3).

```
from BeautifulSoup import BeautifulSoup
soup = BeautifulSoup(open("NATI_front_page.htm"))
print soup.findAll('td', "yfnc_tabledata1", limit = [2:3])
```

I use the following code and I get this:

```
PS C:\python27\stock_program> python pe_ratio.py
[<td class="yfnc_tabledata1"><span id="yfs_j10_nati">3.80B</span></td>, <td    class="yfnc_tabledata1">3.48B</td>, <td clas
s="yfnc_tabledata1">49.15</td>]
```

However, I would like to make my code work and do something like this without the error:

```
from BeautifulSoup import BeautifulSoup
soup = BeautifulSoup(open("NATI_front_page.htm"))
print soup.findAll('td', "yfnc_tabledata1", limit = [2:3])
```

And show:

```
49.15
```

Thanks for your help and suggestions in advance.

Comment: If I understand correctly, you only want the second and third results? You could always set limit to 3 and ignore the first result.

Comment: I want to write it into a CSV file eventually.

Comment: `import csv` - see http://docs.python.org/2/library/csv.html (especially the examples at the bottom of the page)

Comment: I add CSV example in my answer below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Python 2.x

```
import urllib2
from BeautifulSoup import BeautifulSoup

page = urllib2.urlopen('http://finance.yahoo.com/q/ks?s=NATI%20Key%20Statistics').read()

soup = BeautifulSoup(page)

all_data = soup.findAll('td', "yfnc_tabledata1")

print all_data[2].getText()

# or - for more elements

for element in all_data[0:3]:
    print element.getText()

# write to CSV

import csv

with open("results.csv", "wb") as f:
    writer = csv.writer(f)

    writer.writerow(["header1", "header2", "header3"])  

    for element in all_data[0:3]:
        writer.writerow([element.getText(), "column2", "column3"])
```

result:

```
47.65
# or - for more elements
3.69B
3.38B
47.65
```

CSV file:

```
header1,header2,header3
3.69B,column2,column3
3.38B,column2,column3
47.65,column2,column3
```